# How best to represent an aggregation of resources in REST

Tags: web-services, http, rest

Suppose I have the collection of a Person resource that is represented by the URI /rest/persons. Each person resource has a collection of Thing resources and that URI is essentially /rest/persons/{id}/things. Now, suppose a client wishes to view all Thing resources without having to go through each person id. What URI should be used for this? Would the following be a good design:

/rest/persons/things

Or should their be some sort filtering via query parameters on the persons collection?

/rest/persons?things=all

Another option would be to separate person and things into two separate URIs (so no apparent parent->child relationship)

Is there a better way, or should this be discouraged. Keep in mind the goal is to limit the number of requests that the client has to make if he wants to get an aggregate of all the Thing resources regardless of who owns them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would model it this way:

```
GET /rest/persons/{id}
GET /rest/persons/{id}?expand=things

GET /rest/things
GET /rest/things?person={id}
```

If `?expand=things` is used, return all the things embedded in the person resource. If it isn't, you can either just return their URIs (preferred) or not return a value.

I would avoid `/rest/persons/things` because I don't like the idea of a collection of things being a peer of a single person. It just doesn't make sense to me.

You should definitely avoid `/rest/persons?things=all` because your request URI says "give me all persons with all their things", but your response is only a collection of things.

Comment: Thanks. Makes a lot of sense to me. Not sure about the expand query parameter on the persons collection though. Wouldn't
GET /rest/persons/{id}/things
Be acceptable? And couldn't I still have
GET /rest/things
As an alternate URI? Or is this a no no in REST?

Comment: @SimeonG  The idea is to save some wire time by only sending the full body of the things if it's desired by the client.  GET /rest/persons/{id}/things is acceptable. I don't like it, but it's not objectively wrong .. I've seen it in a lot of places. I would also suggest not having multiple URIs which represent the same thing if you can avoid it - it confuses clients and adds to your support burden.